# Background color doesnt apply with Tailwind but work with inline style

Tags: html, tailwind-css

Not quite sure what I am doing wrong here. If I try to apply a background color via Tailwind then it doesn't apply the color but if I try to do it via inline style then it works (inline style copied from Tailwind documentation)

This does not apply the Background color
'''

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <title>Testing Tailwind</title>
  </head>
  <body class="h-screen">

    <div class="h-full">
      <div clas="h-full bg-rose-900">
        <h1 class="text-blue-900 text-center text-4xl">Boards</h1>
        <p>Test</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

'''

This does apply the background color
'''

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <title>Testing Tailwind</title>
  </head>
  <body class="h-screen">

    <div class="h-full">
      <div clas="h-full" style="background-color: rgb(136 19 55);">
        <h1 class="text-blue-900 text-center text-4xl">Boards</h1>
        <p>Test</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

'''

The background color I took from the Tailwind documentation

bg-rose-900 background-color: rgb(136 19 55);
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color

Hoping someone can point me in the correct direction on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Typo: `clas` is missing an `s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo of `class` as @Quentin pointed.

Change

```
<div clas="h-full" style="background-color: rgb(136 19 55);">
```

to

```
<div class="h-full" style="background-color: rgb(136 19 55);">
```